# Facebook Open Graph API Global Actions

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

Is there a comprehensive list of all global actions? Is it just the watch/read/play/listen mentioned here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Global Actions are `like`, `watch`, `read`, and `play` according to their developer docs at [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/?refid=20&ref=pymk&*ft*=fbid.154475804670516&_fb_noscript=1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/?refid=20&ref=pymk&_ft_=fbid.154475804670516&_fb_noscript=1)

If you're using the JSDK, you don't include your app namespace when setting a "Global" action:

```
FB.api('/me/video.watches', 'post', 
    { 
        video : "LINK TO YOUR VIDEO META DATA",
    }, 
    function (respononse) {
        console.log(respononse);
    }
);
```